# Highcharts: Add a custom menu Copy to clipboard

Tags: svg, highcharts, blob, png, clipboard

I wish to add a custom button in highcharts export menu to copy to clipboard with chrome, but it doesn't work and I get the error "Failed to read or decode Blob for clipboard item type image/png".

In my code I am trying to convert an svg image of the chart to png and create a blob then run ClipboardItem on chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/vmjwr0fo/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],

    exporting: {
        buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        menuItems: [
                            {
                                text: 'Copy to clipboard',
                                onclick: async function()
                                {
                                    const svg = this.getSVG();

                                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                                    canvas.width = 1200;
                                    canvas.height = 900;
                                    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                                    const img = document.createElement('img');

                                    img.onload = function()
                                    {
                                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                                    };

                                    img.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg))));

                                    const data = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(img);

                                    const pngImageBlob = await new Blob([data], {type: "image/png"});

                                    try
                                    {
                                        await navigator.clipboard.write([
                                            new ClipboardItem({
                                                'image/png': pngImageBlob
                                            })
                                        ]);
                                    }
                                    catch (error)
                                    {
                                        console.error(error.message);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: There is no feature in exporting module to save chart directly to clipboard, have you checked solution from this [article](https://techozu.com/clipboard-api-domexception-javascript-fix/) about `Error: Document is not focused`?

Comment: I don't have the error "Error: Document is not focused" in my project when I run on chrome, the error "Error: Document is not focused" only appears in jsFiddle, but I would like to have information on the error "Failed to read or decode Blob for clipboard item type image/png", please.